# Swift - changing container from viewController

Tags: swift3, containers, segue

[image]

In the main viewController, I placed Container View and 2 buttons below it. I want to change only the container part by these buttons. Default is showing container1 and when the button2 is pressed, container part switches to container2. How should I do this?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/) article, I made my version and it works.
[image]

In his article, he sets alpha value of container2 as 0 in interface builder. However, this didn't work for me. So, I set alpha values in interface builder 1 for both containers as below screen shots. [image][image]

and here is the code for main viewController.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var containerViewA: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var containerViewB: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // below sets the container1 as default
        self.containerViewA.alpha = 1
        self.containerViewB.alpha = 0

    }


    @IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {

        self.containerViewA.alpha = 1
        self.containerViewB.alpha = 0

    }

    @IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {

        self.containerViewA.alpha = 0
        self.containerViewB.alpha = 1

    }

}
```